# Key Value list created from Json, convert back to Json

Tags: c#, json

I have used some code to convert various `Json` files into a key value list. I now need to be able to reverse the procedure and recreate the original `Json`. Shown below is an example of some `Json` and the code that creates the key value pairs.

My questions is, is there a `Json` library that will convert the key value list back into json or will the process be to parse each key programmatically and recreate each `Json` element?

NB: This isn't a question on how to create a list from `Json` as I will already be given the list. The question is how to convert the list back to `Json`. Shown below is an example of so random `Json`, my work will involve similar `Json` which has nested collections etc.

Original Json:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "isAlive": true,
  "age": 25,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    },
    {
      "type": "mobile",
      "number": "123 456-7890"
    }
  ],
  "children": [],
  "spouse": null
}
```

The Json to key value list output:

[image]

The Code that does the Json to list conversion:

```
static void Main()
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
    var obj = JObject.Parse(json);

    var result = obj.Descendants()
                    .OfType<JProperty>()
                    .Select(p => new KeyValuePair<string, object>
                (p.Path, p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array || p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object
                        ? null : p.Value));

    var keyValueResult = result.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Please, explain which problem do you have with your current code

Comment: I have no problem with my current code. That does not need to change. It has generated a key value list where the key is the path to the value in the original json. What I am after is a way to convert the list back into json. I cannot change the key value list, that is something that the business provides and I have no control over. What I need to do is recreate the original json from the list. I am asking if there is a feature of one of the many json libraries that may help in doing this. If no one has heard of one then I guess I will manually have to recreate the nested json.

Comment: To convert a list back you should store the full path to every property in original JSON and convert it back manually. Json libraries won't do this magic for you. If you aren't allowed to change a key value list, recreating a source JSON is only an option here

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski As my example list shows, I store the full path. I assumed from my Google search that it was going to be a manual process but thought I'd check here in case someone knew of a library that wold help to do "some" of the hard work.

Answer (score 2):

The library I prefer is Json.Net from NewtonSoft 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

Then you can post your JSON into this tool:
http://json2csharp.com/

This will generate your C# classes for you like this:

```
public class Address
{
    public string streetAddress { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public bool isAlive { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
    public List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public List<object> children { get; set; }
    public object spouse { get; set; }
}
```

Then you read and re-serialize your JSON like this:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Then to serialize you do this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RootObject );
```

This makes it much easier.

Comment: You don't really need `json2charp`. You can just copy the JSON to the clipboard, go to `edit -> paste special -> paste JSON as classes` in Visual studio.

Comment: The key / list pair is stored in a database and that is fine for me. I need a way of taking what's in the keys and values and turning it back into Json. I have no need to generate classes. The example Json is just an example, I have to handle all types of nested json and be able to return it to json when required.

Comment: @Retrocoder :  You asked for a library to help you, so this is the example I provided.  a Lot of DBs will output data already in JSON format, so why not look into that instead.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith My question is how to take an existing list of key value pairs and create json from it at run-time. Each list will hold different structures so I don't think your answer helps me achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can user JObject to access the value using the key

```
         string json = @"{
  'channel': {
    'title': 'James Newton-King',
    'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com',
    'description': 'James Newton-King\'s blog.',
    'item': [
      {
        'title': 'Json.NET 1.3 + New license + Now on CodePlex',
        'description': 'Announcing the release of Json.NET 1.3, the MIT license and the source on CodePlex',
        'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx',
        'categories': [
          'Json.NET',
          'CodePlex'
        ]
      },
      {
        'title': 'LINQ to JSON beta',
        'description': 'Announcing LINQ to JSON',
        'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx',
        'categories': [
          'Json.NET',
          'LINQ'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}";

JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);

string rssTitle = (string)rss["channel"]["title"];
// James Newton-King

string itemTitle = (string)rss["channel"]["item"][0]["title"];
// Json.NET 1.3 + New license + Now on CodePlex

JArray categories = (JArray)rss["channel"]["item"][0]["categories"];
// ["Json.NET", "CodePlex"]

IList<string> categoriesText = categories.Select(c => (string)c).ToList();
// Json.NET
// CodePlex
```

You can find more [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Json.Net where you have the provision to serialize and deserialize your hein object using JSONCONVERT